# Unity - Strange shadows/colors in editor

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with the unity **editor** (not with an object in the stage). Is not that bad but is really annoying.

As you can see in the image below, when I select an input field the background color for the whole component is changed (and it looks really bad). It looks like a shadow over the right side (in this case). This also happens with the navigator on the bottom.

[image]

Edit: I add one more picture... in submenus it gets way worse:

[image]

I'm running latest unity version on windows 10. Any idea how I can get rid of the issue?

Comment: I'm also running latest unity version on windows 10 but never faced this issue. Downloading / installing unity again might fix this.

Comment: Is a fresh installation. Has like... 5 minutes :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after a lot of research (since unity is such a common word and most things I found were referring to projects) I found out that the msi nahimic application (that came with my default drivers + apps pack) conflicts with unity 3d (have no idea why that would happen but...).

More details here (there is a link in the answers that leads to an answer from an unity dev): https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=265083.0

Since I understood the problem was resource race for dx 11 (apparently) also found multiple fixes like:

- Close nahimic (obviously) - worked
- Force dx 9 - worked but editor was looking kind of bad
- Force dx 12 - worked best for me (still have some minor issues with text rendering in editor -> is a bit... pixelated, like is low res or something but is really not that bad)